# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на вкладку All отобразился контент с всех трех предыдущих вкладок на JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть три вкладки с контентом, и четвертая новая (All) хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатии на All отобразился контент трех вкладок.

Я конечно мог бы в самом html cоздать div c названием All поместить контент всех вкладок туда, но думаю это плохая идея, потому что вкладок может быть штук 15 например или даже больше и на каждой страничке контент может быть очень большой, получится слишком большая html страница, возможно даже на несколько тысяч строк, если много контента...

Мне кажется наверное это можно как-то реализовать с помощью несколькоми строками на JS. Но как?

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}


document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Весь код в песочнице:
https://jsfiddle.net/nathan111777/5dzrqu3b/4/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName = undefined) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function showCity(event){
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "block";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  event.target.className += " active";
}


document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="showCity(event)">All</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Цикл for всего лишь берет код и кругами выполняет его. Так что

```
for( let i = 0; i < link.length; i++ ){
  tab[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

то же самое, что и

```
tab[0].style.display = 'block';
tab[1].style.display = 'block';
tab[2].style.display = 'block';
```

При клике на кнопку - надо было циклом пройтись и по очереди показывать всё.

"Потому что вкладок может быть штук 15 например" — В таком случае можно задолбаться и с редакцией id и onclick... легче привязать переключения к конкретному классу:

```js
let link = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
let tab  = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
let all  = document.getElementById('all');
for( let i = 0; i < link.length; i++ ){
  link[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    for( let j = 0; j < tab.length; j++ ){
      link[j].classList.remove('active');
      tab[j].style.display = 'none';
    }
    all.classList.remove('active');
    
    this.classList.add('active');
    tab[i].style.display = 'block';
  });
}

/******/

all.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for( let j = 0; j < link.length; j++ ){
    link[j].classList.remove('active');
    tab[j].style.display = 'block';
  }
  this.classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
} 

.link.active, #all.active { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="link active">1111</button>
<button class="link">2222</button>
<button class="link">3333</button>
<button id="all">All</button>

<div class="tab" style="display: block;">вкладка-1</div>
<div class="tab">вкладка-2</div>
<div class="tab">вкладка-3</div>
```